# "Set as default" doesn't work

Tags: 18.10

I was trying to change the default apps for file types, but it didn't work (I tried for PDFs and videos). It didn't change the default program, it stayed the same.

I used this method:

> Right click -> Properties -> Open with -> [select app] -> Set as default

I tried doing it as root (using Nautilus through the terminal), but nothing.
I recently installed Debian and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: The setup of default app is stored in this file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` - Please check that it exists and that you have write perm on it `chown $USER:$USER  ~/.config/mimeapps.list; chmod 644  ~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Comment: Editing the file manually worked. Problem solved, as far as I'm concerned. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.